# ¿Cómo codificar una contraseña en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, php5

Me gustaría poder cifrar o codificar una contraseña en PHP. Quise utilizar la función [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) pero me di cuenta que la versión de PHP que hay en el trabajo no es compatible, utilizo la versión 5.3.3 de PHP.

¿De qué manera puedo hacer esto sabiendo la versión de PHP que tengo?

Había leído hace mucho tiempo sobre MD5, SHA1 y similares pero por ahí supe que ya no son tan seguras como antes. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: crea un salt , y encriptas la clave con el salt

Comment: Md5 no es inseguro _per se_, pero es _relativamente_ economico el algoritmo (en ciclos de reloj) y eso lo hace menos deseable porque es mas simple/barato hacer un ataque por _fuerza bruta_ ... ambos no son reversibles ni nada parecido. pero `bcrypt` o `scrypt` por ejemplo, necesitan mas tiempo de ejecucion haciendo mas costoso el ataque por fuerza bruta. En ambos casos para hacerlo, el atacante necesita tener tu archivos hashes.

Comment: Te dejo esta url con una clase Bcrypt que puedes utilizar... suerte. https://github.com/cosenary/Bcrypt-PHP-Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otro ejemplos para proteger la clave, te recomiendo mezclar varias de las opciones que te damos

```
$clave="Test";
$salt="241241241221341234";
$cadena_encritpada = (openssl_encrypt(base64_encode($clave),"AES-128-ECB",$salt));
echo $cadena_encritpada ."--<br/>"; 
$cadena_desencriptada=base64_decode(openssl_decrypt(($cadena_encritpada),"AES-128-ECB",$salt));
echo $cadena_desencriptada;
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto debe funcionarte con tu versión de PHP.

Para crearlos puedes utilizar este código

```
// Generas un salt aleatorio
$salt = substr(strtr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22)), '+', '.'), 0, 22);
// 2y selecciona bcrypt como algoritmo http://php.net/crypt
// 12 es el factor de trabajo (bastante estándar poner ese número)
$hash = crypt($password, '$2y$12$' . $salt);
```

Para verificarlos simplemente:

```
if (crypt($_POST['password'], $hash) == $hash) {
    // Aqui esta verificado
}
```

A partir de la versión 7.0 creo que el parámetro `salt` de `crypt` ya no es necesario porque se genera uno en cada llamada.