# Login con contraseña encriptada en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo un registro de usuarios, el cual pide email, nombre y contraseña. la contraseña que ingresa el usuario es encriptada para luego ser guardada en una base de datos. Luego en mi pagina de login quisiera que el usuario al ingresar su email y contraseña pueda loguearse facilmente, pero al tener la contraseña encriptada no puedo encontrar el codigo que las compare y verifique que la contraseña que ingreso el usuario sea la misma que la que ya esta registrada en mi base de datos. adjunto mi archivo php re registro de usuarios.

```
    if (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['nombre']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['contraseña']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['confirm_contraseña']) >= 1) {
        if($_POST["contraseña"]==$_POST["confirm_contraseña"]){
            $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
            $email = trim($_POST['email']);
            $contraseña = trim($_POST['contraseña']);
            $contraseña_encryp = password_hash($contraseña, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios(email, nombre, contraseña) VALUES ('$email','$nombre','$contraseña_encryp')";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
            if ($resultado) {
                header('Location: ../index.php');
            } else {
                ?>
                <script languague="javascript">
                    window.alert("¡Ups! ah ocurrido un error");
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            ?>
            <script languague="javascript">
                window.alert("¡Ups! sus contraseñas no coinciden");
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <script languague="javascript">
            window.alert("Por favor complete todos los campos");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Luego en mi pagina de login tengo un archivo html el cual a través de un form envía los datos a "validar.php"

```
<form action="validar.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electronico">
        <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="password" name="confirm_contraseña" placeholder="Confirme su contraseña">
        <input type="submit" name="ingresar" class="ingresar" value="Ingresar">
</form>
```

y el archivo validad.php tiene el siguiente codigo

```
<?php

$email=$_POST['email'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];

//conectar a la base de datos
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registro_usuario");
$contraseña_encrypt="SELECT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'";

if (password_verify($contraseña, $contraseña_encrypt)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}?>
```

Aquí es donde no puedo comparar la contraseña ingresada por el usuario con la registrada anteriormente y almacenada en mi base de datos... no se mucho del tema y por ahí no logro explicarme de manera correcta o no encuentro los términos adecuados, pongo casi todo mi código para que puedan comprenderme mejor.

Comment: Alli te falta algo importante, estas comparando la contraseña ingresada con una consulta, y esta mal, se supone que al hacer la consulta debes obtener el resultado que te arroja la base de datos y asi compararla con la que pusiste en tu formulario

Comment: `$contraseña_encrypt="SELECT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'"; ` esa linea no me guarda el resultado de la consulta en la variable $contraseña_encrypt?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo codificar una contraseña en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77275/c%c3%b3mo-codificar-una-contrase%c3%b1a-en-php)

Comment: @FranSchiavone No, eso no te esta guardando el resultado de la contraseña, simplemente estas diciendo que ```$contraseña_encrypt``` es igual a ```"SELECT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'";``` por lo tanto no esta buscando nada, ya que nisiquiera estas conectando a la base de datos

Comment: Pero tranquilo, ya estoy formulando una respuesta para ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es el siguiente:

1. Estas declarando que la variable `$contraseña_encrypt` es igual a `"SELECT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'";`, despues de alli no haces mas que intentar validar esa variable con password_verify y lo que hace es devolverte FALSE

**SOLUCION**

ATTE: La manera en que se esta consultando no es recomendada ya que esta propensa a inyecciones sql, pero no te voy a enredar tanto para que sepas como es el proceso

```
//Obtienes los datos enviados por el formulario
$email=$_POST['email'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];

//conectar a la base de datos
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registro_usuario");
//Declaro la consulta
$consulta="SELECT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'";
//Preparar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
//Guardo en la variable $row los datos obtenidos de la consulta
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
//Si haces un echo a row[0] deberia devolverte la contraseña encriptada de la bd
//Ahora le doy el valor de la clave obtenida en la bd y la coloco en la variable $contraseña_encrypt
$contrasela_encrypt = $row['0'];
if (password_verify($contraseña, $contraseña_encrypt)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}?>
```

Si la contraseña es correcta deberia devolverte la contraseña es valida

Esta misma pregunta yo la realice hace un tiempo, te invito a pasar si quieres orientarte un poco referente a las consultas preparadas para asi evitar inyecciones sql

[Validar datos guardados por el hash argon2i](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/397833/validar-datos-guardados-por-el-hash-argon2i)